# In CDK step functions, how to pass the commands or environment variables from the state input to the container?

Tags: aws-step-functions, aws-cdk

I have a job like in [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-ecs.html), where the "Command.$": "$.commands" line in ContainerOverrides passes the commands from the state input to the container.

This is input of the step function

```
{
  "envs": [
    {
      "Name": "AWS_REGION",
      "Value": "us-west-2"
    },
    {
      "Name": "KMS_KEY",
      "Value": "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:123456789:key/aaaa"
    },
..... and bunch of env variables.
  ]
}
```

This is step function definition I want to get.

```
{
 "StartAt": "Run an ECS Task and wait for it to complete",
 "States": {
   "Run an ECS Task and wait for it to complete": {
     "Type": "Task",
     "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
     "Parameters": {
                "Cluster": "cluster-arn",
                "TaskDefinition": "job-id",
                "Overrides": {
                    "ContainerOverrides": [
                        {
                            "Name": "container-name",
                            "Environment.$": "$.envs" 
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
     "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to do same thing in the CDK, but it seems like `sfn.Context.entireContext` is string type.

```
        const ecsFargateTask = new tasks.RunEcsFargateTask({
            cluster: props.cluster,
            taskDefinition: props.taskDefinition,
            containerOverrides: [
                {
                    containerName:"DefaultContainer",
                    environment: ??????????????????????????????????????
                }
            ],
            integrationPattern:sfn.ServiceIntegrationPattern.FIRE_AND_FORGET,
        });
```

Comment: What is sfn.Context.entireContext? Environment expects a TaskEnvironmentVariable object. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-stepfunctions-tasks.TaskEnvironmentVariable.html

Comment: @Vikyol i know that `Environment expects a TaskEnvironmentVariable object. `. `sfn.Context.entireContext` is input as a string, so the code above is invalid. I would like to convert  `"Environment.$": "$.envs"`

Answer (score 2):

Found out two ways to achieve this depends on your CDK version:

- `>= 1.48.0`, use `sfn.JsonPath.taskToken('$$.<PATH>')` in the `value` field
- Prior to `1.48.0`, use `sfn.Context.stringAt('$$.<PATH>')` in the `value` field

Other things to point out when trigger fargate/ecs from step function, the input parameters are actually being modified internally so the parent path should be `$$.Execution.Input.<attributes>`, instead of just `$$.<attribute>`

Reference:

- https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9292
- https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9253

Answer (score 0):

maybe using low level step function task would help.

```
const task = new sfn.Task(this, 'ExplanationEcs', {
    inputPath: "$",
    resultPath: "$.ecs",
    task: new class implements sfn.IStepFunctionsTask {
        bind(): sfn.StepFunctionsTaskConfig {
            return {
                resourceArn: "arn:aws:states:::ecs:runTask.sync",
                parameters: {
                    "LaunchType": "FARGATE",
                    "Cluster": props.cluster.clusterArn,
                    "TaskDefinition": taskDefinition.taskDefinitionArn,
                    "Overrides": {
                        "ContainerOverrides": [{
                            "Name": "ExplanationContainer",
                            "Environment.$": "$.envs"
                        }]
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create 2 TaskEnvironmentVariables via `@aws-cdk/aws-events-targets.TaskEnvironmentVariable`, then assign those as a list to the "environment" key:

```
import targets = require('@aws-cdk/aws-events-targets');

const envVar1 = new targets.TaskEnvironemtVariable({
    name: "AWS_REGION",
    value: "us-west-2"
});

const envVar2 = new targets.TaskEnvironmentVariable({
    "Name": "KMS_KEY",
    "Value": "arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:123456789:key/aaaa"
});

const ecsFargateTask = new tasks.RunEcsFargateTask({
            cluster: props.cluster,
            taskDefinition: props.taskDefinition,
            containerOverrides: [
                {
                    containerName:"DefaultContainer",
                    environment: [envVar1, envVar2]
                }
            ],
            integrationPattern:sfn.ServiceIntegrationPattern.FIRE_AND_FORGET,
});
```

Comment: Hello Calvin, thank you for your answer but that's what I meant, I updated my question. What I wanted to get all the environment variables even if I pass any list of env variables.